# Связь одной модели с двумя другими

Tags: orm, django

Есть 2 модели A, B и модель Picture. Надо сделать так, что бы к моделям A и B можно было прикрепить несколько картинок. Не могу понять как сделать связь.

```
#admin.py
class PictInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = Picture
  extra = 3

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [PictInline]

class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [PictInline]
...

#models.py
class A(models.Model):
   ...
class B(models.Model):
   ...

class Picture(models.Model):
   obj = # Что писать?
   picture = models.ImageField()
```

Если я не ошибаюсь то делается это через contentType, но не могу ума дать как?(

P.S. ВСЕХ С ДНЕМ ПРОГРАММИСТА!

Comment: Не совсем ясен вопрос и не понятно зачем тут contentType, но если очень хочется, то для модели Picture добавь такие поля:

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

работать потом можно так: pic.content_type = a, где pic = Picture() и a = A()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ManyToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships) | [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships) и далее по тексту)

Comment: Либо вы не правильно поняли вопрос, либо я Ваш ответ
Тут главный вопрос не в том как сделать, что бы к одному объекту сделать несколько картинок, а как сделать что бы модель Picture можно было прикрепить или к А или к B, причем несколько.

Comment: @Fuzzz3r вы не поняли ответ. Добавляете в модель `A` и `B` поля типа `ManyToManyField` в которых целевой моделью выбираете `Picture`:

    class A (models.Model):
        images = models.ManyToManyField(
            'Picture'
        )

собственно всё - `a_object.images.all()` вернёт все `Picture` относящиеся к объекту…